# What are the terms for the process of closing a business or a company?

Tags: word-request

Can one say "I am closing my business" ? or how can one phrase it ?

Comment: *Shut down/up* or *close down* might work

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase for this in American English would be "going out of business."  For example, [this article](https://moneywise.com/a/chains-closing-the-most-stores-in-2020) uses this term a number of times (also "went out of business" in the past tense), and many more examples can be found online.

A store might, for example, have a "[going-out-of-business sale](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/going-out-of-business-sale)" to sell off all its assets.  This process of selling off of all assets can also be more formally referred to as "[liquidation](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/liquidate.asp)"—converting all of the business's assets into cash.

Comment: Even if one is closing it by choice ? not because of bankruptcy ?

Comment: @BigfootAdam Yes, these terms apply to any reason.  It's also not unheard of for businesses to be forced out of business due to financial reasons other than bankruptcy.  For a purely voluntary closure that's not brought on by any problems, I don't think there's a specific phrase for that.  It's probably best to note that explicitly if you want to make that clear.

Comment: In Britain we would call it a 'closing-down sale'.